# Android based Barcode scanner handled device - possible to transform the barcoded input?

Tags: android, barcode, barcode-scanner

Hello fellow developers

In our warehouse, we are using Android based barcode scanner like the one in picture below

[image]

These are Android 11 devices

Some of the barcodes we scan are for the locations and can be easily spotted because they have always the same structure like aaa000-bbb000

We would like to transform this string and add some dashes for a new system

The new system only accept data like aaa-000-bbb-000 that s why we would like to programmatically add 2 dashes in the string we scan.

First idea would be to relabel everything, but that would mean thousands of barcode to update and a complete mess.

is there any way (thinking about accessibility features) to:

- Detect when a full string is barcoded (act like an input method I guess)
- replace and transform (for that, I can do, no issue) the full string
- act like the new string is used by the closed source application we are using

Thanks a lot for any suggestion

Comment: There surely is, but we know extremely little about your software stack so you probably won't be able to get a lot of specific information. What software is running on them? Do you have the source available? If not, then I'd suggest this isn't a programming question at all (or maybe an exceedingly vague one).

Comment: @JoachimSauer yes, this is programming, i Need to build a listener that will stand between the scanner and the closed source app to transform the string

Comment: Do don't give much programming details, how should we know how your barcode scanner communicate with the backend? In general I would build a custom system all barcode scanners communicate with where you can transform the scanned codes and then transmit them to your closed source backend.

Comment: Because the barcode scanner is buit into the Android system and I cannor read android source code

Comment: I don't think Android comes with a barcode scanner, so that's probably some custom software installed on those devices. From your description it sounds like it acts like a keyboard (or input method). Is this correct? So to summarize: some software outside of your control puts data into some *other* software outside of your control and you want to manipulate that data, right? (this might read like I think it's impossible, but I don't. I just want to clarify that this is indeed the issue here).

Comment: If you did not write the scanner firmware, and you did not write the "closed source app", you hopefully have no means of intercepting the communications between those, let alone modify those communications, except if the scanner firmware has a specific hook for that. Have you contacted developer support for the scanner to ask them?